# How to use class in another class in this same folder using PHP?

Tags: php

I have a folder `test`. In this folder I have a two classes, `TestHeader` and `TestHeaders`.
This is `TestHeader` class

```
<?php

class TestHeader
{
    public function send(): void
    {
    }
}
```

This is `TestHeaders` class

```
<?php

class TestHeaders
{
    public function profile(int $userId): TestHeader
    {
        return new TestHeader();
    }
}
```

And when I run tests, show me error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "TestHeader" not found in C:\project\test\TestHeaders.php:7` I don't know why show this error. Someone could me explain why this error is and how I can fix it ?

Comment: _"I don't know why show this error."_ - because you did not include the TestHeader class file, and are apparently not using any autoloading mechanism either.

Comment: I should add `include "testHeader.php"` to TestHeaders file ?

Answer (score 0):

if you'r not using a php framework that implement the autoload and if you not set up an autoload strategy you have to include all file you'r trying to use in another file.

add `include("TestHeader.php");` at start of `TestHeaders` class, on the line immediately after the `<?php` tag

Comment: That's not working, because show me error `Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Argument #1 ($source) must not be empty in`

Comment: Share all error message. i tried to recreate the case and everything works fine. the only error in your shared code is the missing include statement.

Comment: @perh22 That error message has absolutely nothing to do with the code you showed in the question, or with the original error.